# SELECT MAX returns the wrong value

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL database with a table called `premisis`. I wish to select the row with the highest `premisisnumber`.

This is the SQL I'm using:

```
SELECT max(premisisnr) AS premisisnr FROM premisis
```

The problem is, SQL Server returns the wrong value! In my table I've got a row with `premisisnumber` 10, but using the SQL statement above returns the row with `premisisnumber` 9.

Why? Also, how do I solve this?

Comment: Please show your table data.  MAX() does return the max value.  Do you have a WHERE clause that you haven't posted?

Comment: What type is that column declared as?

Comment: The datatype of your column is `CHAR`. Change it into a numeric type (integer).

Comment: is the column you want the max value from premisisnr or premisisnumber ?

Comment: Try something like `SELECT MAX(CAST(premisisnr AS INT)).....` and I'm pretty confident that SQL Server **will** find the maximum numerical value and return that! But if you **have** a number, then **store it as a number** ! (and don't stick it into a `char` or `varchar` column and expect SQL Server to know that it's really an number....)

Comment: @marc_s: It's 11 years past 2001 and we still have no HAL to do these things for us :(

Answer (score 16):

It sounds like premisisnr is not a number value but is rather a char or varchar value.  What is happening is that SQL Server is sorting based on the character string rather than numeric value.  So 10 comes before 9 because 1 as a character comes before 9 as a character.

The ideal solution would be to change the premisisnr field to either an int or a numeric value.  If that is not an option, you could do the following:

If premisisnr is an integer value:

```
select max(cast(premisisnr as int)) as premisisnr from premisis
```

If premisisnr is a decimal value, you will have to cast as a decimal to the precision and scale you need.

Comment: +1 I'll add that if the column data type can't be changed it might be prudent to mention a where clause (other than `ISNUMERIC()` which is unreliable for specific numeric types) that can weed out garbage that made its way into that column from causing an error, or a check constraint that can prevent garbage in the first place.

Comment: Very valid points.  My experience is that sometimes the reason that a column can't be changed is because some application is databound to it as the data type that it is.  So there may not be any character garbage, but other constraints can sometimes come into play from the application layer.

Comment: Sure, but the application can't stop all the ad hoc nonsense that might go on. I never trust constraints even one tier away from the data (I also don't hand out permissions allowing users to disable constraints / triggers etc. either :-)).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I changed the varchar to int and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that you have a character datatype (char, nchar, varchar etc).

To get the max of a numeric field correctly, you must use a numeric field, e.g. int

Change the data type to int and the MAX() will work.