# Why doesn't LAST_VALUE return the last value?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to find the last value of `y` over an ordered partition using a query like this:

```
SELECT
  x,
  LAST_VALUE(y) OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y ASC)
FROM table
```

But `LAST_VALUE` returns lots of values that aren't the last value (in this case, the largest value) of `y` for a given partition. Why?

(In this case, `MAX` can be used instead of `LAST_VALUE` to find the largest value, but why doesn't `LAST_VALUE` return the max value too?)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**TLDR:** The query you want is:

```
SELECT
  x,
  LAST_VALUE(y) OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y ASC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM table
```

Possibly followed by `GROUP BY` to collapse duplicate output rows from the analytic function.

And of course, it's simpler to just use `MAX` over an unordered partition if that's all you need:

```
SELECT
  x,
  MAX(y) OVER (PARTITION BY x)
FROM table
```

---

Before answering this question, here's a little background on analytic functions (a.k.a. window functions). All of the below is standard SQL and not specific to BigQuery.

First, analytic functions are not aggregation functions. Whereas aggregation functions collapse multiple input rows into a single output row, analytic functions compute exactly one output row for every input row. So you need to make sure you're thinking about what the output is for *every* input row.

Second, analytic functions operate over a "window" of rows that is a subset of the "partition" to which the row belongs. The partition for an input row is determined by the `PARTITION BY` clause, or you can omit it if you want the partition to be the entire set of input rows. The window is given by the `ROWS` clause, but if you don't specify it (and users usually don't), it defaults to either the entire partition (when no ordering is applied) or the set of rows in the partition from the first row to the current row (when an `ORDER BY` is present). Note that the window can differ for each input row in a partition!

Now, back to `LAST_VALUE`. Although the default window described above is reasonable in many cases (e.g., computing cumulative sums), it works spectacularly poorly with `LAST_VALUE`. The `LAST_VALUE` function returns the value of the last row in the window, and by default the last row in the window is the current row.

So to fix the problem, you need to explicitly specify that the window for `LAST_VALUE` is the entire partition, not just the rows up to the current row. You can do so as follows:

```
SELECT x, LAST_VALUE(y) OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y ASC
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM table
```

To test this out, here's an example:

```
SELECT
  x,
  FIRST_VALUE(x) OVER (ORDER BY x ASC) first_asc,
  FIRST_VALUE(x) OVER (ORDER BY x DESC) first_desc,
  LAST_VALUE(x) OVER (ORDER BY x ASC) last_asc,
  LAST_VALUE(x) OVER (ORDER BY x DESC) last_desc,
FROM
  (SELECT 4 as x),
  (SELECT 2 as x),
  (SELECT 1 as x),
  (SELECT 3 as x)

x,first_asc,first_desc,last_asc,last_desc
1,1,4,1,1
2,1,4,2,2
3,1,4,3,3
4,1,4,4,4
```

Note that `LAST_VALUE` returns 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of just 4 because the window changes for each input row.

Now let's specify a window that is the entire partition:

```
SELECT
  x,
  FIRST_VALUE(x) OVER (ORDER BY x ASC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) first_asc,
  FIRST_VALUE(x) OVER (ORDER BY x DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) first_desc,
  LAST_VALUE(x) OVER (ORDER BY x ASC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) last_asc,
  LAST_VALUE(x) OVER (ORDER BY x DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) last_desc,
FROM
  (SELECT 4 as x),
  (SELECT 2 as x),
  (SELECT 1 as x),
  (SELECT 3 as x)

x,first_asc,first_desc,last_asc,last_desc
1,1,4,4,1
2,1,4,4,1
3,1,4,4,1
4,1,4,4,1
```

Now we get 4 for `LAST_VALUE` as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This had me stumped for ages. I hit on the FIRST_VALUE by DESC workaround but couldn't understand why LAST_VALUE wasn't working.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! :-)

Comment: Great. your answer was so complete.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Even that question title uses `LAST_VALUE`  - the question itself asks for `Largest Value`!
I would just go with below:

```
SELECT x, MAX(y) OVER (PARTITION BY x) FROM table
```

And if no other fields from table involved  - i would just do simple GROUP BY:

```
SELECT x, MAX(y) FROM table GROUP BY x
```

Of course, we shoudl remember that not always Largest value and MAX value are the same thing.

Comment: I asked and answered this question because we frequently get customer complaints where users think they've found a bug in LAST_VALUE, and I figured it'd be useful to make it available as a FAQ on SO. I've modified the question so that MAX isn't a valid answer, and I've added a note to my own answer. Thanks for the note!

Comment: sure, that was my exactly thought. i was not sure though what exactly was the user's question as it was a little fuzzy because of wording :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant "..we should remember that not always.." - Am I to blunt when I append a link to what I think you refer to? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398457/select-max-returns-the-wrong-value

Answer (score 0):

Other option you have is to change the query order by to desc

```
SELECT
  x,
  LAST_VALUE(y) OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y ASC)
FROM table
order by x desc
```

but the you will get the last value only for the first row