# LAST_VALUE() is returning second to last value instead in some cases

Tags: sql-server

This particular query returns the second to last value in some instances, but the last value in other instances. Either my checker column is wrong, or this query needs a bit of a button up.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

           a.[Item]

           LAST_VALUE(b.[Date]) OVER(PARTITION BY b.[Item2] ORDER BY b.[Date] RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)


FROM
           [DB1] as a

LEFT JOIN 

           [DB2] as b on a.[Item] = b.[Item2] 

WHERE a.[Block] = 0 AND a.[SafetyValue] = '0'



ORDER BY a.[Item];
```

Maybe my lack of progress is due to a misunderstanding of the RANGE / ROW between?

I looked at this solution: [Why doesn't LAST_VALUE return the last value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096414/why-doesnt-last-value-return-the-last-value)

and it was doing the same thing.

Edit: Turns out it's correct....my checker column was unsorted.

Comment: I would suggest your `PARTITION BY` is wrong then. The reason for the problem in the linked question was due to the lack of `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`, which you do have. An [mre] will help us help you. *Side note: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)*

Comment: Both helpful articles, thanks!